# Factoring out from non-polynomials

Tags: calculus, functions

May be an elementary question to ask: For non-polynomials how is the quotient function

$$\dfrac{ f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}$$

found?

Only if $y= x+\epsilon, $ it becomes the derivative by definition.

How is it related to $ df(x)/dx,\,df(y)/dy?\,$

Also how to find

$$ \frac{x^y- y^x}{x-y},\frac{x^e- e^x}{x-e}, \dfrac{f(x,y)-f(y,x)}{x-y}$$ 
etc.?

Comment: The point of the derivative is to find the limit of the difference quotient. This means bound it as close to the limit as is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking about how to simplify the difference quotient when using the definition of the derivative as the limit of the slope of the secant.

The short answer is that there is no standard method. What works for polynomials does not generalize.

The last few expressions in your question are quite different. The numerators in those fractions are not of the form $f(x) - f(y)$ for a function $f$ of one variable.

Comment: Not even one example can be found !?